# Codeigniter bootstrap like Zend

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, controller

Is there any way to create a function that works for all controllers in Codeigniter at init?

In Zend there is a application/Bootstrap.php, i need some solution like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend the native `CI_Controller` class and create a `MY_Controller` class that all of your application's controllers would extend.  Methods in the `MY_Controller` class would then be available to every controller that extends it.  You could also put code in the `MY_Controller` constructor that would be executed each time a child controller was constructed.

I don't remember exactly how the Bootstrap file works in Zend, but if this sounds like a viable solution the [Creating Core System Classes](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html) section of the documentation explains how to extend the native controller.

Comment: Nice solution, cute Codeigniter!

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your New_controller to CI_Controller. In New_controller you can write common function which you want. For use about new extended controller you can see this link:

The subject of extending core controllers is discussed briefly in a few places in the manual - specifically in the Core Classes and Creating Libraries pages.

The intent of extending the core Controller is to provide methods and attributes to all your normal Controllers.  There are other ways of providing this kind of pervasive functionality - including Hooks, Libraries and Helpers.  You should familiarise yourself with the methods and benefits of those alternatives before assuming the following is the answer to your question.

Finally, it’s assumed that you have an application that does something - it doesn’t matter what, merely that you have an existing Controller that we can work with here.

-[extend_the_CI_Controller](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/MY_Controller_-_how_to_extend_the_CI_Controller)

Comment: Be aware that link contains directions for CodeIgniter 1.7.

Comment: I have extended it in latest versions. It works. You can see discussion link from that page. I have extended answer. It's upto programmer what he uses. I have given other options also.